# how to append ++1 to an attribute value in a List of Pojo's if attributes has same value using java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a huge data pulled from db to List as shown below

```
List<TestVO> aList=new ArrayList<TestVO>();     
TestVO testVO=new TestVO();
testVO.setName("val1");     
testVO.setTime("Time is --1");              
TestVO testVO2=new TestVO();
testVO2.setName("val2");        
testVO2.setTime("Time is --2");     
TestVO testVO3=new TestVO();
testVO3.setName("val1");        
testVO3.setTime("Time is --3");
aList.add(testVO);
aList.add(testVO2);
aList.add(testVO3);
```

Now i want to append "_"+1 for every similar value of next Pojo's Name attribute in the given list.
Finally list should have the pojo's like below

```
TestVO [name=val1_1, time=Time is --1]
TestVO [name=val1_2, time=Time is --3]
TestVO [name=val2, time=Time is --2]
```

Please suggest if i can use any Java 8 API's ? 
i have tried using Comparator to find duplicates but not able to modify nave data ? appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You could do things in two steps :

Collect into a Map the TestVOs that have duplicate names and then modify the name for them.

```
List<TestVO> aList = new ArrayList<TestVO>();      
//...
Map<String, TestVO> vosByName =
aList.stream()
     .collect(groupingBy(TestVO::getName))
     .values()
     .stream()
     .filter(l -> l.size()>1)      
     .forEach(list -> { 
                      int i = 1;
                      for (TestVO vo : list){
                        vo.setName(vo.getName() + "_" + i++);
                      }
                   }
     );
```

Comment: You got it wrong, `.collect(groupingBy(TestVO::getName))` returns `Map<String,List<TestVO>>`. In your case, you are considering the values of map entries as a `Long` meaning the number of `TestVO` that have the same name.

Comment: I know it. I forgot  the `size()` invocation that is `e.getValue().size()`

Comment: you could make it a bit neater to some extent with `.forEach(list -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, list.size())
                      .forEach(i -> list.get(i-1).setName(list.get(i-1).getName()+"_"+i)));`

Comment: @BoristheSpider Nobody tries to advertise the `forEach(add)` anti-pattern. There is no result list and no `add` operation here. This operation is modifying the already existing `TestVO` objects, whether you copy their references into another list or not. Adding the creation of another list would be a disguise.

Comment: @Holger got you - sorry for being obtuse this morning.

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I have tried to reduce temporary object creation, because you work with huge list, and create duplicates is not good.

```
public static void resolveDuplicates(List<TestVO> aList) {
    Map<String, Integer> nameCount = new HashMap<>();
    aList.forEach(testVO -> nameCount.compute(testVO.getName(), (name, count) -> Optional.ofNullable(count).orElse(0) - 1));

    for (TestVO testVO : aList) {
        String name = testVO.getName();
        int count = nameCount.get(name);

        if (count == -1)
            count = 0;
        else
            testVO.setName(name + '_' + (count = Math.max(count, 0) + 1));

        nameCount.put(name, count);
    }
}
```